# Rename columns not working with multiindex dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe, rename, multi-index

I have a very simple code where I try to rename a multiindex dataframe df. The code doesnt work

| cusip | mkt_val |
| --- | --- |
|  | PORT |
| A | 25% |

Code

```
df.rename(columns={('mkt_val','PORT'):'market_val'},inplace=True)
df
```

However there is no change in the dataframe columns name. what is more strange is that when i change the column name to a random name and the code is not producing any error

```
df.rename(columns={('zzz','PORT'):'market_val'},inplace=True)
df
```

The code runs without erroring out and produces the original dataframe

why does this happen?

Comment: By default errors are ignored during pandas renaming - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

You can enable them using `ignore`  flag.

Comment: Any thoughts on why my original code to rename existing multiindex column names doesnt work?   df.rename(columns={('mkt_val','PORT'):'market_val'},inplace=True)